# PD curses compile on windows

Tags: mingw, pdcurses

The makers of PDcurses said it will work on windows.

Using MINGW32 and msys I tried `./configure` But it raised an error :

> no ipc header files.

Others said that ipc doesn't exist on windows.
Please help me how to build it.

Comment: You may be configuring for X11, see the win32/README file.  Or, install with `mingw-get install pdcurses` and `mingw-get install libpdcurses`.

Comment: make -f mingwin32.mak

Comment: @BrianTiffin Do you want to make that comment into an answer? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩  Done, thanks.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 and thanks for the edit fix.  Better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be configuring for X11, see the win32/README file.

Or, install with `mingw-get install pdcurses` and `mingw-get install libpdcurses`.